# Connecting and playing with Cassandra in Java

Tags: java, cassandra

I have read some tutorials on what Cassandra is and what it can do but my problem is how to interface with Cassandra in java? (A tutorial will be nice :-) )

If possible, can someone please show me whether I should use Thrift or Hector (which one is better and why)?

Thanks in advance.

**PS** Can I integrate Hibernate with Cassandra?

Comment: If you haven't looked at it, you can check out the code snippet (example of Thrift usage):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147006/invalidrequestexception-in-cassandra

Comment: give [Hector](https://github.com/rantav/hector) a try

Comment: This doesn't help. I have used Hector before and Thrift. Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for some Hibernate-like library for Cassandra, Kundera (https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera) is a good option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hibernate uses JDBC Drivers to connect to relational databases. Cassandra is a ColumnFamily based, which is A relational database (distributed one).

The problem is to find a proper JDBC driver for your case. Here is a project I Googled:

http://code.google.com/p/sql4d/

It's not active currently, but you got the idea of how to find the right one.

Having object-relationship mapping through Hibernate you won't have to worry about the specific dialect Cassandra use and just enjoy the ride.

Well.. that's how it sounds theoretically.

Yet another way is using Pelops library for usage of Cassandra. More info on it [HERE](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/pelops-the-beautiful-cassandra-database-client-for-java/).

[Getting started with Cassandra](http://schabby.de/cassandra-getting-started/) - a rather short post on the matter.

Hope you find of your answers there!

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help me at all. I want to know what's the best tool/library that works for Cassandra in Java? Also, how to do read/write/etc. The curious thing was if I could integrate Hibernate with Cassandra but if it's not possible, I'm open for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, btw...I didn't give you a negative score.

Comment: It would not be a problem if it was you - after all it's an expression of personal opinion ;)

Comment: Dude, for your great effort. I'm accepting your solution. The links did help.

Comment: Happy to help :)

I'm a little curious what's the project you need Cassandra. Is it something specific, or just getting to know the technology?

Comment: We are actually developing a medical system. Due to the complexity of the information doctors keep (and the fact that there is duplication of patient data, don't ask, doctor confidentiality clause) we needed a database that could allow duplication as well as fast retrieval. Relational is out since your table has to be normalized and here we didn't need normalization.

Answer (score 3):

New for 0.8 is CQL (Cassandra Query Language), an SQL-alike alternative to the traditional RPC interface. Language drivers are available for:

Java (JDBC)
Python (DBAPI2)
Twisted

http://cassandra.apache.org/download/

http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/api/cql_ref

Comment: Yes, I am aware about CQL. I have shown in [my blog](http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.com/2011/08/interfacing-with-apache-cassandra-08-in.html) on how to use the new Thrift in Cassandra 0.8.x.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate OGM looks like it might eventually be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Some example projects using Hector:
https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-tutorial 
https://github.com/zznate/cassandra-stress

Another example (within the actual project) but using using the CQL JDBC driver with our (shiny new) JDBC-pool:
https://github.com/riptano/jdbc-conn-pool/tree/master/portfolio-example