# Problem with apache-cassandra 0.8.2

Tags: java, cassandra

I want to integrate apache-Cassandra as my Database. I have downloaded 0.8.2 version of it. But it seems that there is having lots of changes made in this version. When I try to find the sample source code of it, I found lack of examples of it. Please anybody help me to get start cassandra 0.8.2 in java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246516/connecting-and-playing-with-cassandra-in-java) before. Unless you specify the changes, Hector is a good library to use with Apache Cassandra.

---

**Update:** Seeing that my [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246516/connecting-and-playing-with-cassandra-in-java) has an accepted answer with obsoleted links, I've managed to write portion of the blog on how to [interface with Apache Cassandra 0.8 in java](http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.com/2011/08/interfacing-with-apache-cassandra-08-in.html). Granted, it has changed from Cassandra 0.6 & 0.7.

Comment: Thanks, 
I have seen your question but non of the links is working...(http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=80), rather i have found one code snippet fromk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147006/invalidrequestexception-in-cassandra

Comment: @Anand Soni, I didn't know that the links failed. It worked last year. I will see where I can get the tutorials.

Comment: No problem. But can you please give me any simple code snippate of cassandra 0.8.2?

Comment: @Anand Soni, I've posted a [blog](http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.com/2011/08/interfacing-with-apache-cassandra-08-in.html) and updated this question to help you out.

Comment: @Elite. Thank you for the code snippet. I have tried it but it gives me one exception like 'UnavailableException()'. Can you tell me why it is happending so? It is happening when I am going to insert data using client object.

Comment: @Anand Soni, I have updated my blog which fixes the `UnavailableException()` problem.

Answer (score 2):

See also the ClientOptions page on the Cassandra wiki: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions

Answer (score 1):

The [datastax](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/index) documentation is good.  In particular there is some documentation with examples for client libraries [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/api/other_highlevel_clients).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, with cassandra version 0.8.4 everything is ok to me, including starting cassandra database server and java source code to connect to cassandra, have you try version 0.8.4 ?